# Parsing Nested XML with Namespaces in PLSQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, xmltable

I have an xml that looks like below

```
<ibm:dept bldg="123" xmlns:ibm="http://www.ibm.com/xmltable">
  <ibm:employee id="144">
    <ibm:name>
      <ibm:first>James</ibm:first>
      <ibm:last>Bond</ibm:last>
    </ibm:name>
    <ibm:office>007</ibm:office>
    <ibm:phone>905-007-1007</ibm:phone>
    <ibm:salary currency="USD">77007</ibm:salary>
  </ibm:employee>
</ibm:dept>'
```

I am trying to parse it using XMLTable function. This is what I have tried -

```
select x.*,
       y.*
 from xml_tab t,
 XMLTable(XMLnamespaces('http://www.ibm.com/xmltable' as "ibm"),
 'ibm:dept/ibm:employee' 
 passing t.xml_data
 columns 
        empid NUMBER path '@id',
        office VARCHAR2(5) path 'ibm:office',
        name XMLTYPE path 'ibm:name' 
 ) x,
 XMLTable(
 'ibm:name'
 passing x.name 
     columns 
            firstname VARCHAR2(10) path 'ibm:first',
            lastname VARCHAR2(10) path 'ibm:last') y
 where t.id =3;
```

However it's errored out with below error

```
ORA-19228: XPST0008 - undeclared identifier: prefix 'ibm' local-name 'ibm:name'
```

Hoping someone could explain the error. cheers!

**Data Set up**

```
create table xml_tab
(
 id NUMBER,
 xml_data XMLType
 );



insert into xml_tab
values(3, XMLType.createXML('<ibm:dept bldg="123" xmlns:ibm="http://www.ibm.com/xmltable">
  <ibm:employee id="144">
    <ibm:name>
      <ibm:first>James</ibm:first>
      <ibm:last>Bond</ibm:last>
    </ibm:name>
    <ibm:office>007</ibm:office>
    <ibm:phone>905-007-1007</ibm:phone>
    <ibm:salary currency="USD">77007</ibm:salary>
  </ibm:employee>
</ibm:dept>'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use qualified names in the `PATH` expressions of the `COLUMNS` clause, then you need to specify the `XMLNAMESPACES` clause ( [Doc.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions228.htm) ).

So you need to individually define `XMLnamespaces` even for the second `XMLTable`

*( alias might change such as `ibm2` for the second table by replacing all `ibm:` by `ibm2:` )* :

```
select x.*, y.*
  from xml_tab t,
       XMLTable(XMLnamespaces('http://www.ibm.com/xmltable' as "ibm"),
                'ibm:dept/ibm:employee' passing t.xml_data columns empid
                NUMBER path '@id',
                office VARCHAR2(5) path 'ibm:office',
                name XMLTYPE path 'ibm:name') x,
       XMLTable(XMLnamespaces('http://www.ibm.com/xmltable' as "ibm"),
                'ibm:name' passing x.name columns firstname VARCHAR2(10) path
                'ibm:first',
                lastname VARCHAR2(10) path 'ibm:last') y                
 where t.id = 3;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=68eea401f0e02caed6afd89a083bd70e)</kbd>